# Not able to SSH into Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ssh

I have installed Raspbian OS. I have configured my Pi's DHCP like this

```
static ip_address=10.1.1.1/8
static routers=10.1.1.1
static domain_name_servers=10.1.1.2
```

I have set 10.1.1.2 to be my Windows PC IP address.
I tried to SSH using PuTTY/git bash it says "access denied".

On my Pi , in `auth.log` I see this

```
Jun  6 19:05:02 pi sshd[839]: error: Received disconnect from 10.1.1.2: 13: Unable to authenticate [preauth]
Jun  6 19:16:27 pi sshd[1134]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.1.1.2  user=pi
Jun  6 19:16:29 pi sshd[1134]: Failed password for pi from 10.1.1.2 port 50601 ssh2
```

Comment: the log does appear to mention a failed password...?

Comment: Yes, but I have the same password , I used this password to log into pi

Comment: can you ping the pi from your windoze pc, and are you sure ssh-server is installed and enabled on the pi?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable SSH on your Raspberry Pi 3.

To enable it run this command raspi-config in the terminal, then go to the advanced menu and select enable SSH.

If you don't have a monitor and you still want to enable SSH on your Pi running Raspbian:

Create a blank file without any extension named as "ssh"
Then place the file in the "boot" partition of your SD card

Answer (score -1):

Run:
`ssh -vvv`

That will show all details. Also, on the Raspberry, check that `sshd` is running by using:

```
ps awx|grep sshd
```